# Sending events via code generation with annotations

Tags: java, annotation-processing

I have a bunch of methods that must send events when called, i.e. something like this

```
public void someMethod(){
    sendEvent("someMethod was called");
    // the method does something
}    

public void someOtherMethod(){
    sendEvent("someOtherMethod was called");
    // the method does something
}
```

I would like to avoid the `sendEvent` method call by doing something like

```
@SendsEvent("someMethod was called")
public void someMethod(){  
    // do something  
}
```

I have heard of annotation processing as a way of generating code at build time. Would this be possible to do? if so could you point me in the right direction (tutorial or docs).

PS: I have searched on the net for tutorials on annotation processing by they all seem to focus on using the reflections API for runtime annotation processing. This is NOT what I want.

Comment: Are you looking to avoid calling the sendEvent() method, or have the annotation processor implement the method for you?

Comment: Isn't `@SendsEvent` and `sendEvent()` require the same amount of typing? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @johncarl I'm trying to avoid calling the sendEvent manually,
@dimoniy If I have 30 different classes that send different events I would have to implement the `sendEvent` method in each of those classes or implement a class that would add an extra dependency to each of my 30 classes (30 is just a number, in reality it's much less).

Comment: Ah, so you're looking for something like an AOP method interceptor?  Like, before this method is called, send the "someMethod was called" event.

Comment: @johncarl yes, exactly.

Comment: Is there a reason you need this feature via annotation processor compile-time code gen (as kapep asks)?

Comment: @johncarl compile-time is more efficient

Answer (score 0):

I think for this feature, annotation processing is not worth the additional effort and complexity. Annotation processors are often used for code generation but it doesn't seems you need to generate any dynamic code for this use case. You would have to:

- Learn the annotation processor and mirror apis (similar to the reflection api but more complex)
- Integrate the processor in your build system
- Let the processor generate classes that monitor the annotated methods.
  How to do this? There are many ways. You could generate a class that extends your class, adds the event call and then executes the original implementation. Other solution probably involve run-time handling of everything and could be done using reflections
- Find a way to load the generated classes instead of you own implementations (DI or something)

Unless you actually *really* need to generate code for this and do everything at compile time, you should probably just do everything at runtime when the application starts. Checking for annotations once in the beginning using reflections should not impact performance in any way. Use a [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) to intercept method invocations and add your event calls.